# Cant get Auth::user() inside resource

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get Auth::user() inside resource, but it returns null.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'test' => Auth::user(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hello, please make sure that your session setup is correct.

Comment: Is it throwing an error or just returning `null`?

Comment: Resource set up through web routes or API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be more precise. Is this resource inside the api.php or inside the web.php? It is important since API is stateless; it is normal to return null if you are trying to access the user inside a route from the api.php and if you are not assigning the `auth:api` middleware to that route.

If the resource is inside the api.php, it should look like this:

```
Route::get('/something', 'Api\SomethingController@toArray')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Otherwise, if it's in web.php and you still don't get the user, try to inspect the browser cookies/sessions and make sure that after you're logged you see that in the storage.